# Share configuration dependencies using extendsFrom with control over order

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, build-error

Received this warning in my gradle build this morning, and trying to figure out how to solve it

```
Adding a Configuration as a dependency is a confusing behavior
which isn't recommended. This behaviour has been deprecated 
and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 8.0. If you're 
interested in inheriting the dependencies from the 
Configuration you are adding, you should use extendsFrom
```

Following up on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64420032/204396)... I was using the configuration as a dependency approach so I could control ordering.

For example:

```
configurations {
  A
  B {
    extendsFrom A
  }
}
dependencies {
  A 'jar1'
  B 'jar2'
}
```

Seems to result in the order of B's path being `jar1;jar2`

But if I want B to be *like A, but override some classes from A*, then I need B's dependencies first.

So I was using this approach:

```
configurations {
  A
  B
}
dependencies {
  A 'jar1'
  B 'jar2'
  B A
}
```

Which results in B's path being `jar2;jar1`

I couldn't figure out a way to get this to work using `extendsFrom`.
Mainly I tried to use `B.extendsFrom(A)` with various syntax in the `dependencies` section but couldn't get that to compile.

Is there a way to get the override/ordering use-case to work using `extendsFrom`?

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's not possible with `extendsFrom`.

I am not an expert on the dependencies area, but what could work for you or give you some ideas is something like:

```
def a = project.configurations.findByName("A")
def b = project.configurations.findByName("A")
b.getIncoming().beforeResolve {
    // If you want to get also dependencies from 
    // configurations that "A" extends use getAlLDependencies
    a.getDependencies().forEach{
        b.dependencies.add(it)
    }
}
```

Note: getDependencies() and getAllDependencies() don't return resolved dependencies, but just the dependencies that were added to a configuration in build script (e.g. A 'jar1'). If you want resolved dependencies you have to resolve A.

Note2: I don't recommend class shadowing as I think you want to achieve. It can bring a lot of unexpected troubles, e.g. app could compile but might not work at runtime. Maybe you should rather do a dependency substitution or resolve conflicts with capabilities (https://docs.gradle.org/7.2/userguide/dependency_capability_conflict.html#sub:declaring-component-capabilities).

Comment: That seems like a useful way to copy the dependencies from one config to another. The Gradle warning message seems to say all forms of that are not a good idea and extendsFrom should be used. Would be nice if you could use an extendsFrom in the dependency section so ordering could be controlled. I am overriding a class in a 3rd party library - not something we like to do but occasionally necessary.